# SAR vs. Delta-Sigma ADC

Tags: adc

I want to digitise a sweep signal. The frequency range is 1-100 Hz and the sweep time is 2 seconds. The amplitude is 4.08 Volts and an offset of 2.04 volts is added. ADC range = 0-4.04 Volts. I am currently using an SAR ADC and it is working fine. Would it be better to use a Delta-Sigma ADC? I need a fast and low power ADC. I can have a resolution up to 12-bits with the SAR and I don't think I need more than that. So the ADC resolution is not an issue.

Thank you!

Comment: A SAR is a building block that can be used within a delta sigma adc. They are not limited to using simple comparators as 1 bit devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your application, either should work fine, but generally, an SAR ADC can run with much less power consumption than an Delta-Sigma, and most common SAR converters enter an almost zero power state unless the input changes.  Under 2 or 3 MHz, I probably wouldn't even think of going with a Delta-Sigma converter.  SAR's also need less signal conditioning on the front end generally.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to go with sigma delta below 2MHz, one being cost per bit of resolution, another being the relationship Breen oversampling and prefiltering